# Installation issues of Jasper Server CE 6.2 on MySQL

Tags: mysql, installation, jasperserver

I'm trying to install Jasper Server CE 6.2 by following steps specified in JasperReports-Server-CP-Install-Guide.pdf file (3.2 Installing the WAR File Using js-install Scripts)

After updating default_master.properties, when I try test run using `js-install-ce.bat test` command, then I'm getting below error (extracted from log)

Error Details

```
do-install-upgrade-test:
     [echo] Checking DBMS host and port:
     [echo] About to validate port: mysql-db.company.com:3306
     [echo]   Port 3306 is OK
     [echo] Done validating port: mysql-db.company.com:3306
     [echo] Validating administrative database connection at jdbc:mysql://mysql-db.company.com:3306/mysql. Phase: [test]
     [echo] For JDBC driver the artifactId and version properties are set:
     [echo]   maven.jdbc.artifactId=mariadb-java-client
     [echo]   maven.jdbc.version=1.1.2
     [echo]   Specified JDBC driver jar exists
[advanced-sql] Failed to connect: Could not connect: Access denied for user 'jasper_admin'@'%' to database 'mysql'
     [echo] Connection failed:
     [echo]   SQLState: HY0000
     [echo]   Vendor specific error code: -1
     [echo]   Message: [Could not connect: Access denied for user 'jasper_admin'@'%' to database 'mysql']

BUILD FAILED
E:\Software-Downloads\jasperreports-server-cp-6.2.0-bin\jasperreports-server-cp-6.2.0-bin\buildomatic\bin\validation.xml:495: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Software-Downloads\jasperreports-server-cp-6.2.0-bin\jasperreports-server-cp-6.2.0-bin\buildomatic\bin\validation.xml:376: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Software-Downloads\jasperreports-server-cp-6.2.0-bin\jasperreports-server-cp-6.2.0-bin\buildomatic\conf_source\db\mysql\db.xml:65: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Software-Downloads\jasperreports-server-cp-6.2.0-bin\jasperreports-server-cp-6.2.0-bin\buildomatic\bin\validation.xml:434: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Software-Downloads\jasperreports-server-cp-6.2.0-bin\jasperreports-server-cp-6.2.0-bin\buildomatic\bin\validation.xml:470: Database doesn't exist. Treating problem with JDBC connection as unrecoverable
```

DB Details from default_master.properties file

```
# database type
dbType=mysql

# database location and connection settings

dbHost=mysql-db.company.com
dbUsername=jasper_admin
dbPassword=jasper_admin_password


# additional database parameters
# (uncomment these if you want non-default settings)

dbPort=3306

# JasperServer db name, sample db names
js.dbName=jasper
# sugarcrm.dbName=sugarcrm
# foodmart.dbName=foodmart
```

Note: User jasper_admin already exists in DB and this connection is tested successfully. Database jasper exists as-well.

I can't connect as root access! Please suggest me if there is any work-around.

Thanks a ton in advance for your help.

[update] In error log, I can see below error

```
 Could not connect: Access denied for user 'jasper_admin'@'%' to database 'mysql'
```

but where I can see what code Jasper build scripts are using to verify this? because, I can connect to MySQL DB using same user via MySQL Client.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with MySQL user "jasper_admin". This user should have access to internal database mysql. Best case is try installing Jasper using MySQL "root" user.